# Getting breed type

Tags: netlogo

In my go procedure, I want to check the breed of my turtles. But I cannot find a way to do it simply. I want to execute different code depending upon the breed. How should I do this?

I define breeds as:

```
breed [late-adopters late-adopter]
```

and in go

```
to go

  ask turtles [
    
    
    if is-late-adopter [do something...]
  ]
end
```

Comment: hi, yes, perhaps this might be of interest http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/if.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to check [the `breed` turtle variable](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#breedvar) against the breed agentset itself.  The [Bug Hunt Predators model](http://staging.netlogoweb.org/launch#http://staging.netlogoweb.org/assets/modelslib/Curricular%20Models/BEAGLE%20Evolution/Bug%20Hunt%20Predators%20and%20Invasive%20Species.nlogo) is a good example of this.  Here is the relevant code:

```
to go
  ; ... 

  ask turtles [
    ;; we need invaders and bugs to eat at the same time
    ;; so one breed doesn't get all the tasty grass before
    ;; the others get a chance at it.
    (ifelse breed = bugs     [ bugs-live reproduce-bugs ]
            breed = invaders [ invaders-live reproduce-invaders ]
            breed = birds    [ birds-live reproduce-birds ]
                             [ ] ; anyone else doesn't do anything
    )
  ]

  ; ...
end
```